# Unable to see comments in intellisense

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

I am developing a .Net library (dll). All the public methods are decorated with full /// comments.

When I hover over one of these methods whilst in the same solution (eg in a test project) I can see the comments as a tooltip.

However when I reference the dll in a different Visual Studio solution, I can't see the comments in the intellisense tooltip.

Is there something I need to do to 'turn this on'? I notice I can see comments when I hover over .Net library methods, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project properties, you need to enable the setting "XML documentation file" under the Build tab - and then keep the generated Xml file in the same folder as your Dll.

Comment: And presumably ensure it is deployed by the installer? It doesn't seem to be automatically included, even though the dll is.

Comment: Yes, if you're redistributing your DLL through an installer, you should include the XML file too. It's not needed for an end-user, but any developer who needs the tooltips will need it to be available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure 'Generate XML documentation file' is enabled in your project settings.

(Compile tab on VB, not sure exactly where it is in C#).